# VS Code - Biztalk Development

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. How do I go about using VS Code to develop on Biztalk 2016?

Let me explain further...

Currently, I have to install Biztalk Server on my PC. Then in Visual Studio a Biztalk project template will be available. I create a new project from this template and voila!

Is it possible to do something like this with VS Code?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code is currently unsupported for BizTalk 2016 project files.